# Application fails to send email with Mail::...queue()

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I'm facing a problem with mails on while using `queue`. If I use Mail with `send()`, everything works fine.

The controller:

```php
Mail::to($order_data->client_email)
    ->cc([
        ['email' => $order_data->seller->email],
        ['email' => auth()->user()->email]
    ])
    ->queue(new SendOrderConfirmation($order_data));
```

The mailable:

```php
class SendOrderConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Defines a public variable $order_data that we will be using to pass in parameters from our controller.
     */
    public $order_data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        // set email data
        $this->order_data = $data;

        // Set Reply to address
        // Basically, the name and email from who's sending this email
        $this->replyto(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);

        // Set from
        $this->from(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);

        // set email subject
        $this->subject('Laminar - Confirmação da Encomenda N.º '.$this->order_data->order_nr);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('send_emails.Lamimail.SendOrderConfirmation');
    }
}
```

If i trigger the email with queue(), I get an error on telescope jobs saying:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object 
(View: path\resources\views\send_emails\Lamimail\SendOrderConfirmation.blade.php)
```

But, in the mail view, the name is a simple `auth()->user()->name`.

Does anyone know that I'm missing with the queue?

Regards

**SOLUTION**, based on @Ersoy feedback. Note the `public $sender_name;`
The mailable:

```php
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Defines a public variable $order_data that we will be using to pass in parameters from our controller.
     */
    public $order_data;

    /**
     * Will be used to save the sender name
     */
    public $sender_name;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        // set email data
        $this->order_data = $data;

        // Set sender name to be used on mail view
        $this->sender_name = auth()->user()->name;

        // Set Reply to address
        // Basically, the name and email from who's sending this email
        $this->replyto(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);

        // Set From
        $this->from(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);

        // set email subject
        $this->subject('subject...');
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('view...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the job or email is `queued`, then you no longer can access to session(variables in the session) because there is no HTTP access when the job "asynchronously" is processed. Because of that you can't get authenticated user(there is no specific user when the job is processed).

You need to send authenticated user(as object or array) to the constructor of the `SendOrderConfirmation` class, then you can use inside the class.

The non-queue will work because it will be `sync` and still session can be used.

Comment: Well explained, already fixed it, tested and working. Will update the question to reflect the changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just sending the name as data by adding it to your `$order_data` and displaying it in the mail blade to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Didn't tried that way. But writed a ```public $sender;``` and in constructor writed ```$this->sender = auth()->user()->name``` and no luck. Suspecting that queue don't work with auth.

Comment: Yes, try that way by adding it to the `$order_data` as it seems you cant access it in the view. So by adding it you can then simply call it in the view.